# Comparison of performance between Scala etc. and C/C++/Fortran?

Tags: c++, multithreading, scala, fortran, mpi

I wonder if there is any reliable comparison of performance between "modern" multithreading-specialized languages like e.g. scala and "classic" "lower-level" languages like C, C++, Fortran using parallel libs like MPI, Posix or even Open-MP.

Any links and suggestions welcome.

Comment: I do believe that performance measurements are application or area specific.  One language may be better at graphics, while another better at searching.  Please give more information about what project or application you are using these languages for.

Comment: Err, yes, of course, I have tried Google ;-) Well, I am just curiouse, no special application. Just wondering a JVM would produce some overhead compared to native c/cpp/fortran binaries. Now: When does the advantange of using Scala etc. & JVM begin compared to native c/cpp/fortran binaries?

An appropiate benchmark setup is, of course, crucial.

Comment: JVM best case is that all normal cases have been executed once to compile them into native code. Plus Java is not designed for speed. Typically portability and speed are on the opposite sides of the design sheet.

Comment: Check out the Parallel Colt project (and other software by Piotr Wendykier).  There's lots of plenty fast parallel Java there, though I've seen relatively little that reaches the astounding number of processors often used via MPI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that Java, and, therefore, Scala, can call external libraries, and given that those highly specialized external libraries will do most of the work, then the performance is the same as long as the same libraries are used.

Other than that, any such comparison is essentially meaningless. Scala code runs on a virtual machine which has run-time optimization. That optimization can push long-running programs towards greater performance than programs compiled with those other languages -- or not. It depends on the specific program written in each language.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another non-answer: go to your local supercomputer centre and ask what fraction of the CPU load is used by each language you are interested in.  This will only give you a proxy answer to your question, it will tell you what the people who are concerned with high performance on such machines use when tackling the kind of problem that they tackle.  But it's as instructive as any other answer you are likely to get for such a broad question.

PS The answer will be that Fortran, C and C++ consume well in excess of 95% of the CPU cycles.

Answer (score -1):

I'd view such comparisons as a fraction. The numerator is a constant (around 0.00001, I believe). The denominator is the number of threads multiplied by the number of logical processors.

IOW, for a single thread, the comparison has about a one chance in a million of meaning something. For a quad core processor running an application with (say) 16 threads, you're down to one chance in 64 million of a meaningful result.

In short, there are undoubtedly quite a few people working on it, but the chances of even a single result from any of them providing a result that's useful and meaningful is still extremely low. Worse, even if one of them really did mean something, it would be almost impossible to find, and even more difficult to verify to the point that you actually *knew* it meant something.

Comment: *0.00001* Where do you come up with that number?

Comment: @Paul: Like 97.4% of all statistics, I made it up off the top of my head. Despite this, I'd challenge anybody to try to come up with a number that's more accurate. Regardless of the exact value, it starts out small, and adding more threads and processors reduces it quickly.

Comment: Possibly amusing, but it's also wrong.  There are plenty of good ways to benchmark performance, and the MPI folks do it routinely, from latency measurements to efficiency with increasing number of processors to breakdowns of communication vs. computation for well-understood algorithms.  It's not an easy question to answer, but questions of this sort are answerable and very worth knowing the answer to if you're planning on burning a million hours of CPU time.

Comment: @Rex:yes, there are lots of ways to benchmark performance. The types of questions you've listed can even be answered with such benchmarks -- but his question is different from those, and isn't answerable. You can't compare Scala to Fortran -- at most, you can compare one particular implementation to another particular implementation. A meaningful answer requires a question that's well-defined and generally quite narrow. His is poorly defined and *extremely* broad, and lacks any meaningful answer.

Comment: @Rex: that's the problem: you can't answer (even in principle) the pieces that make up the answer. If (for example) you find that implementation X (using Scala) is 10% faster than implementation Y (using Fortran) you can only **speculate** that the difference you're seeing really has anything to do with Scala vs. Fortran. The next week, Y might be upgraded to be 20% faster than X -- but whether it is not not, it still tells you nothing about Scala vs. Fortran.

Comment: @Jerry: It's not that mysterious.  You code the same algorithm in both languages.  You profile each, compare bottlenecks.  Maybe you twiddle one or the other to get better performance.  Either way, if you're competent, you'll get good ballpark numbers.  Then adjust the task to vary just e.g. the communications volume.  Measure again.

Comment: @Rex:At least to me it's mysterious how you think this constitutes a test of the language instead of a test of one specific implementation of the language.

Comment: @Jerry: Care to write another version of Java + JVM from scratch?  No?  Then I think the specific implementation is important.  You don't get vastly improved performance from a new C++ every few weeks, you know.  These things are pretty stable.

Comment: @Rex:If there's any logic in your comment, I must be failing to grasp it. How does the fact that I'd consider it unethical to loose yet another Java compiler on the world change the fact that what you test is an implementation, not a language?

Comment: @Jerry: The distinction between a language and the specific implementation you have access to is immaterial if you can't get access to any other implementation.

Comment: @Rex:Access to only a single implementation might restrict your interest to that implementation, but is completely immaterial to the distinction between the language and the implementation.